# Using email+password user authentication, allow admin to change user email address

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

We would like to be able to use the email+password authentication model with firebase. However, our app will have user roles defined and stored in our data, controlling what each user can access. We would like the admin users, those with the highest role, to be able to update the email address of a user. Currently it looks like the only function I see for this, changeEmail, requires the password to be passed in. Is there any way to allow an admin in the system to update the email address of a user without knowing the users password?

Comment: This seems like a bad idea to me, surely you would just be screwing people over? Why would you want to change a user's email manually?

Comment: Imagine a situation where a user changed their email address and can no longer access their old email address. Also, imagine this user can't remember their password, because it was always saved in the system and they didn't enter it all the time. This user cannot use a password reset since they can't access their email. So, they call up the support team and ask for their email to be reset. Note: the app I am making is not open to the public, it is an internal business app, so there is no concern over verifying the user is who they claim to be. Also, new users are created by the support team.

Comment: Additional thought - without the ability for the support team to change a users email address, I think the only other solution is to build a "merge" functionality, where records for one user are moved to another user. This seems like a lot of work personally. Alternatively, I can implement the custom authentication as well.

Comment: Creating a secured route for transfering data from one user account to another wouldn't be hard at all. All you need is an input where you can type the user id and it will run a small function which fetches the data from one user id and push it to another. To me this would seem like the best solution. Then you can just remove the old account from Firebase and quickly create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Firebase SDK 2.5.0, it isn't possible to run `changeEmail()` or any of the auth methods without having the user's current password.

The only administrative option would be a migration: Delete the account in the app dashboard, create a new one with, replacing existing `uid` in database with new `uid`.

Comment: Kato - I believe the second item, using resetPassword(), would only work if the user still has access to their email address. If they don't know their password, and they no longer have access to their email to get the reset link, the only option is the first item you listed.